# Bootstrap CSS file does not work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am just new to bootstrap and trying to make a fully responsive tempelate but the problem is when I attach css and js file there is no effect comes and the path is also right. So,please help me any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: provide some code where you are actually facing problem @Hiten Pandya

Answer (score 0):

Check path for the files are correct. Use developer tools (console) to check whether files are loading in the browser or not. Try to include the files using CDN, if working then try to correct the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you are actually using bootstrap classes. Ex -> class="btn btn-default"

But most likely your path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a good code editor like PHPStorm. PHPStorm for example will check for you if the path to the linked file is correct by using some colors. Also, you can try to use a CDN (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). That will include your files from a server so you dont have to have your files in your own files structure. Try to use my starter template, it will work and I am using CDN paths.

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Bootstrap starters template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <style>

    </style>



</head>

<body>





<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>


</script>

</body>

</html>
```